# django-crispy-forms: Change name of input

Tags: django-crispy-forms

I am running into some minor problems with `django-crispy-form`.

I currently have a form, which successfully displays all fields from my model.

However, I would like to change the html-attribute `name` to something else. I realize this might be difficult, since `django-crispy-forms` probably expects the name to be the same as the field in the model.

I managed to change the `id`, but the `name` will not update. Any chance that there is a fix for this, other than changing the name of my columns in my database?

#### Example code

```
from django import forms
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper

class CompanyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CompanyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].widget.attrs['id'] = 'company_n' # works
        self.fields['name'].widget.attrs['name'] = 'company_n' # does not work

        self.helper = FormHelper()
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the column name in the model is the way to change the name attribute of fields of a `ModelForm` form.
In my experience, that shouldn't be a problem for sanely designed models.

A good guide to efficient data modeling in django is:
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2018/02/10/django-tip-22-designing-better-models.html

Answer (score 0):

This is the top google search result, so here is a method that works for me.  Note that this is actually not a crispy forms question, it applies to all Django forms.

Of course there are times when you need to change the label on a form - one example would be a different label for an admin user or a regular user.

Just set the `label` property on self.fields.  Here's a complete example:

```
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import Div, Field, PrependedAppendedText
from django import forms
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Submit


class MyModelEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Make changes to my model"""
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['my_field', ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # this is the magic right here:
        self.fields['my_field'].label = "Foo"
        # this should answer your next question, which is how do I change the text under the field
        self.fields['my_field'].help_text = "Bar"
        self.helper = FormHelper
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        # I have found that it's important to be explicit about the form layout, or you'll get all kinds of CSS issues
        self.helper.form_id = 'my-model-form'
        self.helper.form_class = 'form'
        self.helper.form_tag = True
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Div(
                PrependedAppendedText('my_field', '$', '.00',wrapper_class='col-md-4', ),
            ),
            Submit('submit', 'Save', css_class='btn-success'),
        )
```